# ModSecurity is behaving funnily in apache2.4 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apache, mod-security, ubuntu

I am trying to put modsecurity in apache 2.4.7 a reverse proxy for a tomcat applcation. For a normal request it's throwing lots of logs about allowed methods even though the method used is get.

```
[Wed Mar 11 10:35:33.187404 2015] [:error] [pid 26124:tid 140113409455872] [client 41.66.208.198] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "within %{tx.allowed_methods}" against "REQUEST_METHOD" required. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_30_http_policy.conf"] [line "31"] [id "960032"] [rev "2"] [msg "Method is not allowed by policy"] [data "GET"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.8"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "9"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/POLICY/METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-15"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A6"] [tag "OWASP_AppSensor/RE1"] [tag "PCI/12.1"] [hostname "pentest.mydomain.com"] [uri "/favicon.ico"] [unique_id "VQAadQoAAGwAAGYM9ykAAABE"]
[Wed Mar 11 10:35:33.187627 2015] [:error] [pid 26124:tid 140113409455872] [client 41.66.208.198] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "within %{tx.allowed_http_versions}" against "REQUEST_PROTOCOL" required. [file "/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_30_http_policy.conf"] [line "78"] [id "960034"] [rev "2"] [msg "HTTP protocol version is not allowed by policy"] [data "HTTP/1.1"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/2.2.8"] [maturity "9"] [accuracy "9"] [tag "OWASP_CRS/POLICY/PROTOCOL_NOT_ALLOWED"] [tag "WASCTC/WASC-21"] [tag "OWASP_TOP_10/A6"] [tag "PCI/6.5.10"] [hostname "pentest.mydomain.com"] [uri "/favicon.ico"] [unique_id "VQAadQoAAGwAAGYM9ykAAABE"]
```

But according to posts at [security.stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38483/modsecurity-errors-related-to-request-method-http-1-1-and-get) and [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/394052/broken-urls-after-enabling-mod-security) I should not have run into that issue.

I do have the following in /usr/share/modedurity-crs/modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf

```
#
# Set the following policy settings here and they will be propagated to the 30 rules
# file (modsecurity_crs_30_http_policy.conf) by using macro expansion.  
# If you run into false positves, you can adjust the settings here.
#
SecAction \
   "id:'900012', \
    phase:1, \
    t:none, \
    setvar:'tx.allowed_methods=GET HEAD POST OPTIONS', \
    setvar:'tx.allowed_request_content_type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded|multipart/form-data|text/xml|application/xml|application/x-amf|application/json', \
    setvar:'tx.allowed_http_versions=HTTP/0.9 HTTP/1.0 HTTP/1.1', \
    setvar:'tx.restricted_extensions=.asa/ .asax/ .ascx/ .axd/ .backup/ .bak/ .bat/ .cdx/ .cer/ .cfg/ .cmd/ .com/ .config/ .conf/ .cs/ .csproj/ .csr/ .dat/ .db/ .dbf/ .dll/ .dos/ .htr/ .htw/ .ida/ .idc/ .idq/ .inc/ .ini/ .key/ .licx/ .lnk/ .log/ .mdb/ .old/ .pass/ .pdb/ .pol/ .printer/ .pwd/ .resources/ .resx/ .sql/ .sys/ .vb/ .vbs/ .vbproj/ .vsdisco/ .webinfo/ .xsd/ .xsx/', \
    setvar:'tx.restricted_headers=/Proxy-Connection/ /Lock-Token/ /Content-Range/ /Translate/ /via/ /if/', \
    nolog, \
    pass"
```

I have used libapache2-modsecurity package and here is what is in the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/security2.conf file

```
 <IfModule security2_module>
    # Default Debian dir for modsecurity's persistent data
    SecDataDir /var/cache/modsecurity

    # Include all the *.conf files in /etc/modsecurity.
    # Keeping your local configuration in that directory
    # will allow for an easy upgrade of THIS file and
    # make your life easier
    IncludeOptional /etc/modsecurity/*.conf
    Include /usr/share/modsecurity-crs/activated_rules/*.conf
 </IfModule>
```

Is there anything I am not doing well? I would appreciate if any one could shed some lights in there for me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see from [the answer you linked to](https://serverfault.com/a/394311), the name of the file should be `modsecurity_crs_10_config.conf`. In your post, you say that yours is instead called `modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf`.

Two other possible problems I see are that your `setvar` lines all have spaces before them whereas the answer does not (but I highly doubt that would cause problems). Also, your `tx.allowed_request_content_type` is separated by `|` instead of .

Changing those would make your file:

```
#
# Set the following policy settings here and they will be propagated to the 30 rules
# file (modsecurity_crs_30_http_policy.conf) by using macro expansion.  
# If you run into false positves, you can adjust the settings here.
#
SecAction \
"id:'900012', \
phase:1, \
t:none, \
setvar:'tx.allowed_methods=GET HEAD POST OPTIONS', \
setvar:'tx.allowed_request_content_type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded multipart/form-data text/xml application/xml application/x-amf application/json', \
setvar:'tx.allowed_http_versions=HTTP/0.9 HTTP/1.0 HTTP/1.1', \
setvar:'tx.restricted_extensions=.asa/ .asax/ .ascx/ .axd/ .backup/ .bak/ .bat/ .cdx/ .cer/ .cfg/ .cmd/ .com/ .config/ .conf/ .cs/ .csproj/ .csr/ .dat/ .db/ .dbf/ .dll/ .dos/ .htr/ .htw/ .ida/ .idc/ .idq/ .inc/ .ini/ .key/ .licx/ .lnk/ .log/ .mdb/ .old/ .pass/ .pdb/ .pol/ .printer/ .pwd/ .resources/ .resx/ .sql/ .sys/ .vb/ .vbs/ .vbproj/ .vsdisco/ .webinfo/ .xsd/ .xsx/', \
setvar:'tx.restricted_headers=/Proxy-Connection/ /Lock-Token/ /Content-Range/ /Translate/ /via/ /if/', \
nolog, \
pass"
```

If none of the above works in fixing the problem, I suggest simply trying to upload the snippet directly from [the answer](https://serverfault.com/a/394311) and see if that works for reassurance:

```
#
# -=[ HTTP Policy Settings ]=-
#
# Set the following policy settings here and they will be propagated to the 30 rules
# file (modsecurity_crs_30_http_policy.conf) by using macro expansion.  
# If you run into false positves, you can adjust the settings here.
#
SecAction "phase:1,id:'981212',t:none,nolog,pass, \
setvar:'tx.allowed_methods=GET HEAD POST OPTIONS', \
setvar:'tx.allowed_request_content_type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded multipart/form-data text/xml application/xml application/x-amf', \
setvar:'tx.allowed_http_versions=HTTP/0.9 HTTP/1.0 HTTP/1.1', \
setvar:'tx.restricted_extensions=.asa/ .asax/ .ascx/ .axd/ .backup/ .bak/ .bat/ .cdx/ .cer/ .cfg/ .cmd/ .com/ .config/ .conf/ .cs/ .csproj/ .csr/ .dat/ .db/ .dbf/ .dll/ .dos/ .htr/ .htw/ .ida/ .idc/ .idq/ .inc/ .ini/ .key/ .licx/ .lnk/ .log/ .mdb/ .old/ .pass/ .pdb/ .pol/ .printer/ .pwd/ .resources/ .resx/ .sql/ .sys/ .vb/ .vbs/ .vbproj/ .vsdisco/ .webinfo/ .xsd/ .xsx/', \
setvar:'tx.restricted_headers=/Proxy-Connection/ /Lock-Token/ /Content-Range/ /Translate/ /via/ /if/'"
```

Comment: I did a copy of that file renamed it to have the config.conf ending and restarted apache but still no luck

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the time wasted for everyone, I have caused this myself. I went on reading on [SpiderLabs github page line 41](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/master/INSTALL#L41) and the first thing that occurred to me was that I ought to either include the file with xx_10_setup.conf in the mods-enabled/security2.conf or do an symbolic link to activated_rules.

So name of the file doesn't matter after all.

Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

On Debian Buster the file to edit is:

```
/usr/share/modsecurity-crs/rules/REQUEST-901-INITIALIZATION.conf
```

Search for: `setvar:'tx.allowed_methods=`

At roughly line 163, edit the line so that it includes the methods you need to accept eg:

```
setvar:'tx.allowed_methods=DELETE GET HEAD POST PUT OPTIONS'"
```

save the file then restart apache:

```
service apache2 restart
```